# Code for backspace button in calculator oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to add backspace button in calculator oracle forms developer

What is the code for backspace button. Remove value from display item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this on trigger `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED`:

```
:yourBlock.field := substr(:yourBlock.field, 0, length(:yourBlock.field) -1);
```

Comment: if we click not at the end but in the middle of string, and start to press that button ..?

Comment: In this case, it's a `Display Item` (not a `Text Item`), so the user can't click or edit the field without using buttons, from what i understood.

Comment: ok, i see, you're right. The point of interest is `not being a Text Item`.